# Create Team City Build configurations using restapi and powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, teamcity

I am trying to create build configurations via the restapi and powershell and keep getting the following error:

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

It seems that I can use `GET` fine, the issue appears to be with the `PUT` command

Code Snippet

```
$url = http://%teamcityServer%:8111/app/rest/buildTypes/id:%projectname%"
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.ContentType = "text/plain"
$req.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$req.Credentials = Get-Credential("username")
$req.Method ="PUT"
$req.ContentLength = 0
$req.Accept = "*/*"
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$results = [xml]$resp.ReadToEnd()
```

Output from the Team City log

> 2015-09-10 09:14:30,582]   WARN [io-8111-exec-70] - est.jersey.ExceptionMapperUtil - Error has occurred during request processing (405). Error: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException. Not supported request. Please check URL, HTTP method and transfered data are correct. metadata: [Allow:[HEAD,DELETE,GET,OPTIONS],] Request: PUT '/app/rest/buildTypes/id:%project%'

Team City Version is 9.1.1 so I believe this is possible.

I'm fairly new to the restapi so any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but you need to post xml data to create builds/projects. For example if you need to create a project you can POST XML something like

```
<newProjectDescription name='New Project Name' id='newProjectId' copyAllAssociatedSettings='true'><parentProject locator='id:project1'/><sourceProject locator='id:project2'/></newProjectDescription>
```

to http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/projects.

Check more info on [Teamcity REST documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-ProjectSettings).

You didn't mention your powershell version, but if you are using 3.0 or later you can call `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet and your code should look something like:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "Application/xml"
```

For PowerShell 2.0 You can write your own Web-Request method like:

```
function Web-Request{   
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Uri,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]
        $Username = $null,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]
        $Password = $null,      

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $ContentType,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Method,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]
        $PostString
    )

    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Uri)
    $webRequest.ContentType = $ContentType  
    $webRequest.Method = $Method
    $webRequest.Accept = "*/*"
    if ($Username)
    {
        $webRequest.Credentials = new-object system.net.networkcredential($Username, $Password)
    }

    try
    {
        switch -regex ($Method)
        {
            "PUT|POST" # PUT and POST behaves similar ways except that POST is only used for creation while PUT for creation/modification   
            {
                if ($PostString -ne "")
                {       
                    $PostStringBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($PostString)
                    $webrequest.ContentLength = $PostStringBytes.Length
                    $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
                    $requestStream.Write($PostStringBytes, 0,$PostStringBytes.length)
                }
                else
                {
                    $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
                }
            }
            "DELETE"
            {
                $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
            }
            default
            {               
                # GET requests usually don't have bodies, default will behave like a GET
            }
        }

        if ($requestStream -ne $null)
        {       
            $requestStream.Close()
        }

        [System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
        $rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
        [System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
        [string] $results = $sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch
    {
        $results = "Error : $_.Exception.Message"
    }
    finally
    {   
        if ($sr -ne $null) { $sr.Close(); }
        if ($resp -ne $null) { $resp.Close(); }

        $resp = $null;
        $webRequest = $null;
        $sr = $null;
        $requestStream = $null;
    }
    return $results 
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, Its actually PowerShell v2.0.which led me to use webrequest
i'll try and get it updated to a later version.
i assume $body will be the xml you're posting?

Comment: Yes $body is meant to be the XML for build/project creation. I have updated the answer and added a Web-Request method to work with PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Nadeem, 
I seem to be getting an error at the following line now
    [System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
Error : Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error
.".Exception.Message

Comment: Update: This is working, now.
Thanks for your assistance Nadeem